# Use a reg file in order to change the value of an entry in the registry

Tags: windows, registry, regedit

I have created a reg-file in order to change the value of an entry in the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...]
"InstallPath"="C:\kkk"
```

The `...` above continues to the full path in my reg-file.

The data-type of this entry is `REG_SZ`, so I have omitted it.

Executing this file does not seem to change the value of that entry.

Does anybody recognize this problem or have any idea where it stems from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing `"C:\kkk"` to `"C:\\kkk" (i.e., was missing a backslash).